# Reorder a provided JSON to a Specified Format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need an optimized way to reorder the following JSON in JavaScript:

```
 [
 {"Values":["2005","Australia","$304749.10"]},
 {"Values":["2005","France","$143130.80"]},
 {"Values":["2006","Australia","$651979.82"]},
 {"Values":["2006","France","$332496.01"]},
 ]
```

into this format:

```
 [
 {"Values":["Australia","2005","$304749.10"]},
 {"Values":["Australia","2006","$651979.82"]},
 {"Values":["France","2005","$143130.80"]},
 {"Values":["France","2006","$332496.01"]},

 ]
```

Comment: Did you try any solutions?

Comment: sorting would help :)

Comment: Why is this being down voted?

Comment: Because stackoverflow is not a place where you come and tell us your requirements and we do your work for you for free. It's a website for specific questions about programming and just simply saying "I need this" is not a specific question.

Comment: Guys,really sorry for this kind of question will take care of it next time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var data=[
  {"Values":["2005","Australia","$304749.10"]},
  {"Values":["2005","France","$143130.80"]},
  {"Values":["2006","Australia","$651979.82"]},
  {"Values":["2006","France","$332496.01"]},
]
```

May reorder the props first:

```
data=data.map(({Values:[year,location,price]})=>({Values:[location,year,price}]));
```

Then sort alphabetically after the first prop:

```
data.sort(({Values:[loca]},{Values:[locb]})=>loca.localeCompare(locb));
```

http://jsbin.com/yekiropozu/edit?console

Note that this uses ES6 object destructuring...

Comment: Really nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could first swap the first two items of the inner array and then sort the whole array by country and then by year.

```js
var array = [{ Values: ["2005", "Australia", "$304749.10"] }, { Values: ["2005", "France", "$143130.80"] }, { Values: ["2006", "Australia", "$651979.82"] }, { Values: ["2006", "France", "$332496.01"] }];

array.forEach(a => [a.Values[0], a.Values[1]] = [a.Values[1], a.Values[0]]);
array.sort((a, b) => a.Values[0].localeCompare(b.Values[0]) || a.Values[1] - b.Values[1]);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Quite nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var data = [
 {"Values":["2005","Australia","$304749.10"]},
 {"Values":["2005","France","$143130.80"]},
 {"Values":["2006","Australia","$651979.82"]},
 {"Values":["2006","France","$332496.01"]},
 ];

 var data2 = data;

 for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 data2[i].Values[1] = data[i].Values[0];
 data2[i].Values[0] = data[i].Values[1];
}
console.log(data2);
</script>
```